# Excel VBA - Extract Specific Data From JSON Response

Tags: json, excel

I have the following JSON response.

```
{
  "Response":"Success",
  "Type":100,
  "Aggregated":false,
  "Data":[
    {
      "time":1511049600,
      "close":342.1,
      "high":348.5,
      "low":336,
      "open":345,
      "volumefrom":231851,
      "volumeto":79568255.7
    },
    {
      "time":1511136000,
      **"close":332.8,
      "high":345.2,
      "low":332,**
      "open":342.1,
      "volumefrom":191805,
      "volumeto":64932181.5
    }
  ],
  "TimeTo":1511136000,
  "TimeFrom":1511049600,
  "FirstValueInArray":true,
  "ConversionType":{
    "type":"direct",
    "conversionSymbol":""
  }
}
```

How can I extract only the second set of "Close", "High" and "Low" (highlighted with **) into excel?

Comment: I would definitely check out [this project](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). There is a nice .bas file you can import into your VBAProject and it allows you to parse natively in VBA. Without it, you would have to parse it yourself possibly line by line, search, set flags, and extract what you need. It won't be pretty.

Comment: thank you @JNevill, I'll try it out